# Cabbage Slaw w/ Teriyaki?

Tags: asian-cuisine, food-identification, cabbage

I recently had some spicy chicken teriyaki.  It came with a side of what was just cabbage in some clear liquid.  I've not had luck identifying it online, any idea what it may have been?

It was a bit tangy and sweet, but nicely balanced out the spicy teriyaki.  It wasn't overly drenched in liquid, but there was a fair amount.  Again, I didn't see any other vegetables.  It wasn't creamy at all, like a coleslaw.

The cabbage was still mostly crunchy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Chinese celery and cabbage appetizer called and how is it made?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46001/what-is-the-chinese-celery-and-cabbage-appetizer-called-and-how-is-it-made)

Comment: They may be similar but that question specifically mentions celery and this one says it was cabbage only. I'm not convinced that they are the same. This is also a side dish and the other was an appetizer... and that question is about Chinese cuisine and this one is about Japanese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a basic Asian Cabbage Slaw. Sometimes the dressing is made with rice vinegar, lemon juice maybe a little sesame oil to make a vinaigrette. I'm sure the dressing is dependent on the restaurant. where did you get it?

Comment: That sounds about right.  I'll have to search for that.... Bellevue, WA

Answer (score 2):

Was the cabbage translucent? If so, this sounds like Japanese [amazu pickled cabbage](http://www.lafujimama.com/2009/07/making-japanese-pickles-washoku-way/).

Comment: Not particularly translucent, but thanks for the idea.